# Manejar versiones de python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9

Buenos días estoy aprendiendo python y tenia instalada la versión 3.9.12, ayer instale desde la pagina oficial de python la versión 3.10.5. Cuando trabajo en VSC reconoce python 3.10.5, en la terminal al ejecutar python3 -V dice que tengo Python 3.9.12; al ejecutar python3.10 -V dice que tengo 3.10.5.

Cuando abro un cuaderno de Jupiter en VSC no reconoce las bibliotecas que tengo instaladas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Salida: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

En un cuaderno de Jupiter hice esto,

```
import sys 
print(sys.version)
```

La salida es: 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi recomendación, especialmente teniendo en cuenta que estás en Mac, es que uses **entornos virtuales**.

### Qué son

A pesar de su nombre misterioso, no son más que carpetas, que tienen dentro una estructura de archivos que contiene una instalación de python y un conjunto de módulos instalados para esa versión.

### Por qué son útiles

Supongamos que quieres trabajar en un proyecto que requiere el uso de jupyter, pandas, numpy y otras bibliotecas de cálculo numérico. En lugar de instalarlas con `pip install` lo recomendable es usar un entorno virtual.

Si usas `pip install` para empezar no es obvio saber qué versión de `pip` será la que estás usando (y por tanto en qué versión de python se instalarán esos paquetes). Puedes acabar instalándolos en una versión de python diferente de la que después vas a usar.

Además las instalaciones con `pip` son "globales", es decir, se instalan en las carpetas de sistema en las que esté instalado python. Eso puede causar problemas si alguna librería de las instaladas fuerza a actualizar otras librerías que tenías instaladas previamente. Puedes encontrar incompatibilidades entre versiones.

Además imagina que mientras trabajas en ese proyecto, quieres iniciar otro que requiere del uso de por ejemplo `pygame`, porque quieres iniciarte en el desarrollo de videojuegos con python. Si usas `pip install pygame` a nivel "global" estarías de algún modo mezclando diferentes proyectos en la misma máquina. Tu python tendría paquetes para diferentes objetivos, todos instalados globalmente.

Un entorno virtual te permite separar estas cosas. Puedes tener un entorno virtual para computación numérica, otro para desarrollo de videojuegos, otro para frameworks de desarrollo web, etc. Ya que cada entorno no es más que una carpeta, cuando dejes de necesitarlo puedes borrar esa carpeta sin más.

### Creación del entorno virtual

Para crear un entorno virtual llamado por ejemplo "computación", darías el siguiente comando:

```
python3.10 -m venv ~/venvs/computacion
```

Lo que va tras `-m venv` no es más que el nombre de la carpeta donde quedará todo guardado. Es buena práctica crear todos tus entornos dentro de la carpeta llamada `~/venvs` (siendo `~` tu carpeta de usuario). Así los puedes encontrar todos fácilmente. Pero realmente un entorno virtual, al ser una simple carpeta, puede estar donde quieras.

El resultado del comando anterior será una carpeta llamada `~/venvs/computacion`. Puedes examinarla y verás que tiene dentro carpetas llamadas `bin`, `lib`, etc... Y dentro de `bin` verás un `python`, `pip`, etc.

Siempre que ejecutes `~/venvs/computacion/bin/pip` para instalar algo, se instalará en ese entorno (en `~/venvs/computacion/lib` concretamente). Y para ejecutar un script con ese entorno lo harás usando `~/venvs/computacion/bin/python mi_script.py`

Pero esto es un tanto incómodo. Es más fácil "activar" el entorno.

### Activación del entorno

Consiste en ejecutar desde una terminal el siguiente comando:

```
source ~/venvs/computacion/bin/activate
```

Observarás que eso cambia tu prompt y le añade `(computacion)` delante. Es un recordatorio de que has activado el entorno. Esa activación no es otra cosa que adaptar ciertas variables de entorno (solo para esa sesión, no tienen efecto permanente) de modo que la carpeta `~/venvs/computacion/bin` sea la primera en tu PATH.

De este modo, poniendo `python` o `pip` "a secas", se ejecutarán los binarios guardados en ese entorno. Y `pip` instalará las cosas en ese entorno.

Así que una vez has activado el entorno puedes poner:

```
pip install pandas
```

y la biblioteca pandas quedará instalada en ese entorno. Podrás probar a usarla ya así:

```
python
>>> import pandas
```

y deberá funcionar, puesto que el `python` que estás ejecutando es el del entorno (en el cual está instalado pandas). Si pruebas `python -V` verás que es la 3.10 (la misma que usaste para crear el entorno)

En cualquier momento puedes poner el comando `deactivate`, que restaurará el prompt y el PATH a como estaban antes.

Recuerda que cada vez que abras una nueva terminal, deberás volver a "activar" el entorno.

### Jupyter

Para que jupyter use el mismo entorno, y así tengas pandas accesible en él, la solución obvia es instalar Jupyter en el mismo entorno. Es decir, te aseguras de que tienes el entorno activado y pones `pip install jupyter`. Y con el entorno activado ya podrás arrancar Jupyter desde esa misma terminal.

Por si no estás muy seguro de qué python o qué pip se están ejecutando realmente, puedes usar el comando `which` del shell. Por ejemplo `which python`, y te mostrará la ruta (que debería ser `~/venvs/computacion/bin`)

### VSCode

Cuando escribes un programa `.py` desde VSCode, éste te ayuda con errores de sintaxis, autocompletado de código, etc. Pero para poder hacerlo bien necesita saber qué interprete python estás usando. O en el caso de que tengas varios entornos virtuales, con cuál de ellos vas a trabajar.

De este modo, si haces al inicio del código un `import pandas`, VSCode podrá hacer ese import para mediante introspección averiguar qué métodos proporciona ese módulo y ayudarte así con el autocompletado del código. Pero claro, sólo encontrará pandas si está usando el python del entorno virtual adecuado.

En VSCOde puedes usar Mayus+Cmd+P y después teclear "Python interpreter" para cambiar qué intérprete de python usar. Te saldrá un desplegable con los que VSCcode haya detectado. Normalmente debería detectar automáticamente los que estén en la carpeta `~/venvs`, así que deberías ver entre ellos "computacion". Pero aún si no lo ves, puedes especificar la ruta hasta un binario python en particular (en este caso hasta `~/venvs/computacion/bin/python`) para que use ese.

### ¿Y después?

Si más adelante instalas otra versión de python, digamos python3.11, eso no afecta a los entornos virtuales que tuvieras previamente creados. Al activar tu entorno "computacion", seguirías usando python3.10. Esto es otra ventaja de estos entornos. Todo está en la versión correcta en la que todo funcionaba antes, por lo que es inmune a cambios de versiones fuera del entorno.

Naturalmente si quieres crear nuevos entornos una vez has instalado Python3.11, lo harías del mismo modo, con `pythonX.X -m venv`, y según qué versión pongas en `X.X`, esa será la versión que quedará en uso en ese entorno.