# from flask import Flask ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

estoy comenzando en programación Python, copie tal cual un ejercicio de you tube, pero no me funciona.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello Word'
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Web\index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

pero tengo flask instalado. aca dejo las versiones por si puede haber alguna incompatibilidad.

C:\Users\Diego>flask --version

Python 3.10.5 Flask 2.1.3 Werkzeug 2.2.0

Comment: Has instalado `flask`??

Comment: Parece que es el típico caso de tener dos versiones de Python instaladas, y haber instalado flask en una de ellas, pero tratar de ejecutar el script con la otra. Mi recomendación es usar entornos virtuales. Mira mi respuesta a esta otra pregunta --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/542878/7123

Answer (score 0):

Debes de instalar flask.
Si tienes ***linux*** y **python3** usas `pip3`, si lo quieres en ***windows*** usas `pip`, pip tambien funciona en ***linux*** pero hace referencia a **python2**
Si quiero instalar flask en python3 y en linux haria esto en una terminal:

```
pip3 install flask
```